# Why am I unable to create an image?

Tags: docker

I used to build and push the image of a service to my preprod server very fast (in a few seconds). However since a few days it is very slow, and today it doesn't even finish creating the image.

```
$ ./middleware-api-docker.sh 
[+] Building 1.3s (15/15) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                 
 => [internal] load build definition from middleware-api                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 41B                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:9-stretch                                                                                                                                             1.2s
 => [auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 1.81kB                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [1/9] FROM docker.io/library/node:9-stretch@sha256:07b483e788713ae0362d77ca26e078f8335dfc0df6d84d4be18acd58f7b09768                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [2/9] WORKDIR /usr/src/app                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [3/9] COPY ./middleware-api/package.json ./package.json                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [4/9] RUN mkdir ./shared                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [5/9] RUN apt-get -y update                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [6/9] RUN npm install                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [7/9] RUN apt-get install -y jq                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [8/9] COPY ./shared ./shared                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [9/9] COPY ./middleware-api .                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:9729884307526ec39a6de5d6ca6f7ae91e2140bedbd26fea3f1ed0260aaf2917                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => naming to preprod.thatsowl.com:4200/middleware-api:latest                                                                                                                                              0.0s

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
The push refers to repository [preprod.thatsowl.com:4200/middleware-api]
e79b8aa5fe44: Pushing [==================================================>]  73.73kB
```

It is stuck in this state.

The script I use to deploy it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# Produce Docker Image for middleware-api
cd ../../..
docker build -t preprod.thatsowl.com:4200/middleware-api:latest -f ./dockerfiles/middleware-api ./webapp
docker push preprod.thatsowl.com:4200/middleware-api:latest
ssh root@preprod.thatsowl.com  << EOF
  /owlab/tools/pull-docker.sh middleware-api
  docker service update --force --image preprod.thatsowl.com:4200/middleware-api:latest owlab_middleware-api
EOF
```

The dockerfile:

```
FROM node:9-stretch
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./middleware-api/package.json ./package.json
RUN mkdir ./shared
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN npm install
RUN apt-get install -y jq
COPY ./shared ./shared
COPY ./middleware-api .
EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 9092
ENTRYPOINT [ "npm", "start"]
```

Docker version:
`Docker version 20.10.11, build dea9396`

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you have slow connection?

Comment: @Justinas no i'm on ethernet. And anyway this would not explain that it looks frozen. It would only be very slow but without being frozen for a few minutes

Comment: Is image size in the same like before? I had a similar case and reason of that was that I left some files like DB dump etc in a directory that I copied to docker image. After that, image had additional 800MB and push took ages.

Comment: "why is the server suddenly slow" is more of a server fault question than a programmer question. And without a lot more debugging details, it's too open ended and unanswerable (kinda like why does my app suddenly exit, it worked yesterday, with no debugging details of what causes that app to exit).

Comment: There's also a screenshot of text which isn't readable by many (search engines, mobile users, and anyone with a visual impairment). Post formatted text instead.

Comment: @BMitch that's not what I asked. I asked why I am unable to deploy a docker image. This is a programmer issue, not a sys admin issue (although you could, if you wanted, also approach the problem with a sys admin perspective). Also I'm a developer, not a sys admin (or anything like this). Also I gave all the details I could given the situation; Docker unfortunately doesn't provide much help in this situation. Also if there's a problem with the screenshot, a comment asking for using text instead of screenshot would be more welcome than a request for closing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out unused images took 99% of the space allowed for images.

```
$ docker system df
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          76        6         13.21GB   13.1GB (99%)
Containers      27        5         34.64MB   33.65MB (97%)
Local Volumes   22        5         0B        0B
Build Cache     371       0         355.8MB   355.8MB
```

Unfortunately, docker did not show an error or warning when creating the image to explain why it only froze, which made the problem difficult to understand.

A `docker system prune -a` fixed the problem.

```
$ docker system df      
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          5         5         3.716GB   0B (0%)
Containers      7         5         994.1kB   4.478kB (0%)
Local Volumes   22        1         0B        0B
Build Cache     0         0         0B        0B
```

After this, I can deploy my service fast again.